# Change form action target without JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, select, dynamic, action

I have a form with select box. With JavaScript on, I take the *change* event to define the options-values as location.hrefs:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    window.location.href = $(this).val();
});
```

With JavaScript off, I have a basic form with a submit button. To follow the targets given in the option values, I have to set them to the form action. Do you have any idea how I could get only the selected option as form target e.g. with any CSS selector or something like that?

The form:

```
<form action="test-1.html">
    <fieldset>
    <select id="lorem">
       <option value="test-1.html">test1</option>
       <option value="test-2.html">test2</option>
       <option value="test-3.html">test3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="senden" class="submit" />
    </fieldset>
 </form>
```

Comment: Without javascript? No. No way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to do this in server-side code. Without JavaScript enabled, there is no way to dynamically change anything in an HTML DOM.

So, submit to some intermediary page that's sole purpose is to redirect and perform the logic there.